# How does StackOverflow Careers determine the country of website visitors by IP?

Tags: support, jobs, technology

I was wondering what service StackOverflow Careers use to determine their visitors location and if they can recommend a service.

Answer (score 4):

There are many methods to do this sort of thing, such as the ever popular [Maxmind GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) system (which ultimately is using whois data).

More accurate geolocation is available in more modern browsers using HTML5 features, but given browsers have to request permission to get this data, this method can be ruled out for the adverts you mention.

Comment: We are in fact using MaxMind. It geocodes not just the Careers home page but the Careers ads you see on SO proper.